# Get placemark from getPlacemarks with Google Maps Android API utility library

Tags: android, kml, android-maps-v2

I'm using [this library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/#start) to show a kml markers in a map in Android Maps V2.
I´m trying to get the lat and lon from a kml layer to do zoom directly to a placemark after add it to a map.

I tried to do this:

```
 layer = new KmlLayer(mMap,R.raw.ruta, this );
 layer.addLayerToMap();
 for (KmlPlacemark act : layer.getPlacemarks()){
      System.out.println("hi");//not iterate
 }
```

but it doesn´t enter in the loop I read this [kml-feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml#features) but don't work as is

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read the 1st container of the KML-layer before attempting to read information about the placemarks:

```
KmlContainer = layer.getContainers().iterator().next();
if (kmlContainer == null) return;

for (KmlPlacemarks placemark : kmlContainer.getPlacemarks()) {
  // Do the placemark magic here!
}
```

Comment: Ok I Will try soon